# Increase slug size on heroku

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku, deployment

How do I increase my slug size to 750MB? I've been trying to deploy a python web app that has tensorflow and numpy and some other dependencies. Tensorflow itself is >400MB, the total size for all the dependencies is >500MB but I only have 500MB as my slug size, what do I do to be able to deploy the Python web app?

Comment: Contact Heroku support?

Comment: They don't provide support for free users.

Comment: Then you will have to reduce the size of your slug or stop being a free user, but we can't make them increase the limit for you.